# i18next adding [contenthash] to taranslation file Name

Tags: webpack, i18next

Using the copy-webpack-plugin, I add [contenthash] to my i18next translation files in the name when building code.

```
{
    from: 'public/locales/',
    to: 'locales/[path][name].[contenthash][ext]',
},
```

At the output I get a file with that name
translation. [contenthash] .json

and of course, when I try to execute the code on the server, I get an error because i18next is looking for files named translation.json.

The question is, can I somehow get [contenthash] in the backendOptions in i18next in the loadPath property?

I know that loadPath can also be a function, but unfortunately only lang and path come there, and I can't generate a hash myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [i18next-http-backend](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend) the loadPath option can also be a function.
This way you could construct your custom path: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend/issues/86

Comment: Yes, I've seen in the documentation, we can pass a function in loadPath that gets languages, namespaces. And based on them change the file download path. But languages, namespaces will not change for an single file when its content changes.
I ask, whether it is possible to receive content of a separate file in function of loadPath and on the basis of content to change a way (to generate a hash)?

Comment: no this is not possible, but you can define your own request function and do whatever you want